# Android Dev: icon in notification bar

Tags: android

I see some apps which place an icon in the notification bar on my device. how do i do that with my app ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) class.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), all the steps are explained very well.